# PHP Multiple Files Upload print blank Array

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, image-upload

This is my form:

```
<form action="?upload=1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="file[]" type="file" multiple />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

This is my php:

```
function make_upload() {
    print_r($_FILES);
}
if (isset($_GET["upload"]) && $_GET["upload"] == "1") {
    make_upload();
}
```

If I try to select only one file then it shows the array with the file in. It's OK.

If I try to select multiple files then it shows `Array ( )`. Why?

Comment: Try `name="file[]"`, otherwise PHP does not recognize multiple parameters of the same name that it gets passed (but overwrites them all with the value of the last one).

Comment: @CBroe - I have tried it. The problem prospers.

Comment: Try printing out the content of $_FILES on top of your script, not making it dependent on a GET value – any difference?

Comment: @CBroe - Tried... It shows `Array ( )`...

Comment: Current code seems good, I haven't found any issues :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is good. No errors founds in it.

Your problem is 100% caused by `post_max_size`.

You need to increase it from your `php.ini` configuration file.

You could increase `upload_max_filesize` too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an array name:

```
<input type='file' name='file[]' multiple>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem prospers.